# R: How to lag xts column by one day of the set

Tags: r, xts

Imagine an intra-day set of data, e.g. hourly intervals. Thanks to Google and valuable Joshua's answers to other people, I managed to create new columns in the xts object carrying DAILY Open/High/Low/Close values. These are daily values applied on intra-day intervals so all rows of the same day have the same value in particular column. Since the HLC values are look-ahead biased, I want to move them to the next day. Let's focus on just one column called Prev.Day.Close.

Actual status:
My Prev.Day.Close column caries proper values for the current day. All "2010-01-01 ??:??" rows have the same value - Close of 2010-01-01 trading session. So it is not PREVIOUS day at the moment how the column name says.

What I need:

Lag the Prev.Day.Close column to the NEXT DAY OF THE SET.

I cannot lag it using lag() because it works on row (not day) basis. It must not be fixed calendar day like:

```
C <- ave(x$Close, .indexday(x), FUN = last)
index(C) <- index(C) + 86400
x$Prev.Day.Close <- C
```

Because this solution does not care about real data in the set. For example it adds new rows because the original data set has holes on weekends and holidays. Moreover, two particular days may not have the same number of intervals (rows) so the shifted data will not fit.

Desired result:

1. All rows of the first day in the set have NA in Prev.Day.Close because there is no previous day to get data from.
2. All rows of the second day have the same value in Prev.Day.Close - Any of the values I actually have in Prev.Day.Close of previous day.
3. The same for every next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's one way to do it:

```
require(xts)
# sample data
dt <- .POSIXct(seq(1, 86400*4, 3600), tz="UTC")-1
x <- xts(seq_along(dt), dt)
# get the last value for each calendar day
daily.last <- apply.daily(x, last)
# merge the last value of the day with the origianl data set
y <- merge(x, daily.last)
# now lag the last value of the day and carry the NA forward
# y$daily.last <- na.locf(lag(y$daily.last))
y$daily.last <- lag(y$daily.last)
y$daily.last <- na.locf(y$daily.last)
```

Basically, you want to get the end of day values, merge them with the original data, *then* lag them. That will align the previous end of day values with the beginning of the day.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Your example is clear and simple to understand. I managed to implement your solution in my code. Thank you very much, Joshua. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote until some reputation level.